# Regular expression not finding any matches to replace text using ansible.builtin.replace

Tags: regex, ansible

I have this Ansible task from a playbook that I am trying to use to replace the occurrences of a hostname found in /etc/hosts with a new hostname set as a variable in /etc/ansible/hosts:

```
  - name: Update /etc/hosts
    replace:
      path: /etc/hosts
      regexp: '^\w+-\w+'
      replace: "{{ new_hostname }}"
```

The hostname of the Ansible target that I am trying to change the contents of /etc/hosts is **webna-host0011**, which is also the pattern I am trying to capture in /etc/hosts and replace all occurrences of.

When I run the playbook, this task is not finding any matches to do a replace on and the /etc/hosts file remains unchanged.

I checked the regular expression using https://pythex.org/ with **webna-host0011** as my test string and was able to get the right match, but this expression finds no matches when used in the task itself.

This is /etc/hosts itself:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

10.12.52.19     webna-host0011.onegrp.com webna-host0011
```

The regular expression matches the hostname itself, but it seems like the match cannot be made due to where it is in the lines of the file itself.

Comment: I think it should be `regexp: '^\\w+-\\w+'`, but it is probably not enough.

Comment: without rule to define what you search, you have to indicate the full name to replace

Answer (score 2):

in your case ie, without rules to define the hostname to replace :

```
 - name: Update /etc/hosts
    replace:
      path: /etc/hosts
      regexp: 'webna-host0011'
      replace: "{{ new_hostname }}"
```

or to replace all strings which contains a - in it (be careful):

```
 - name: Update /etc/hosts
    replace:
      path: /etc/hosts
      regexp: \w+-\w+'
      replace: "{{ new_hostname }}"
```

Comment: i dont understant why its not functional see the link test, or you have something special in your etc/host  could you show it ?...

Comment: your line begins by ip and not by hostname?

Comment: thanks for suggesting (?m). I added the contents of /etc/hosts from the target. It seems like the match isn't happening because of where the hostname is in the lines of the file.

Comment: in your case why dont replace directly the name of your old host?

Comment: I got the regexp parameter to find matches in the context of the hosts file by getting rid of the carat '^' at the beginning, so `\w+-\w+` matches the hostname occurrences in /etc/hosts in the playbook run and testing with pythex.

Comment: yes but be care because all strings with a - inside it will be replaced

Comment: Is there a way to use quantifiers to replace only the first two occurrences of this pattern and leave all occurrences that follow alone?

Comment: You can't indeed have `^` to start your regex as `^` means *at the beginning of the line*, while at the beginning of your host line, you do have, at least an IPv4

Comment: @KelvinA.Vasquez  you dont precise what you want...is the first two occurences of file or first two occurence of each lines?

Comment: @KelvinA.Vasquez  to avoid confusion, i suggest you to show the initial file and the file waited...